# Kernel Panic not showing up?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I'm writing a kernel module and I was hoping to get the beautiful **Kernel Panic** screen with all the details when I call `panic()`, but my machine just freezes without displaying anything.

I know kpanic is not displayed in X11 GUI mode, but my code switches to text-mode before calling `panic()`.

So the scenario looks like this:

```
switch_to_text_mode();    /* switch to text-mode (i.e. CTRL-ALT-F1) */

sleep(5);                 /* to make sure text-mode is running */

panic("useful stuff");    /* kpanic */
```

My kernel version is **5.3.0**

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/panic`? See `man proc` for information.

Comment: @Sman865 The output is 0. I tried setting it to 60 as recommended [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt), but no luck.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that would be it. What about setting `panic_on_oops` to 1?

Comment: Nothing, unfortunately :/ I noticed that documentation for `panic_print` is titled:
_Bitmask for printing system info when panic happens_ . It was set to 0 (bit 0: print all tasks info).

I tried all combinations from the documentation (the link I posted above), but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

For panic_print to work, you may need a serial console, as other console may not work properly in the panic context.

Comment: This seems like it might be helpful for OP, can you add some more details for how they can set this up? Putting the most relevant parts in your answer and providing a link to the source will make this a more useful answer.